# Some emoji show up as black squares for others

Tags: ios, unicode, markdown, emoji

I use these emoji in my markdown file to color code:

However, for at least one other person using iOS, these show up as black squares like this □. I'm not sure how to diagnose or fix this, as they don't show up as black squares on my screen, and I'm pretty new to iOS.

I suspect it has to do something with updating the latest emoji, as these are part of the Emoji 12.0 collection, a newer one released in 2019.

Is there some sort of link that updates their emoji, or some work around?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some sort of link that updates their emoji, or some work around?

No. If your system is not far enough advanced, you are missing the most recent emoji and you just won't see anything, or won't see anything useful, when one of those emojis appears in some text.

Comment: what causes this though? is this fixed by updating the iOS? or is it something else? i looked up some other newer emoji and saw that i am also missing some of the more recent emoji, how would i fix this?

Comment: You would also need to update. It's the only way; they are part of the system itself.

Answer (score 0):

These color squares were introduced in Unicode 12.0 and Emoji 12.0, and require iOS 13.2 or higher to view properly.